# Switch and Constructor Component (React) to Change Source when passing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I apologize up front, I am new to React.  I am really struggling to get this to work.  The end desired result is that when given a selection of a few options in a prop array, a switch changes which is image is rendered and presented.  Utilizing React 17.02, Gatsby, Prop-Types.  Please don't beat me for how dumb my mistake is ;)

```
import { array, oneOf, PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import { StaticImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"


class LogoComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {type} = this.props
    this.props = {
      type: 'standard'
    };


  }
  

  render({this.props.type}) {
   switch ( { this.props.type }) {
    case 'standard':
      return  
    <>
    <StaticImage
      src="./horizontal/white.webp"
      alt="White Logo"
      placeholder="blurred"
      layout="fixed"
      width={100}
      height={25}
        />
        </>;
    case 'darkversion':
      return  
          <>

<StaticImage
      src="./horizontal/black.webp"
      alt="Black Logo"
      placeholder="blurred"
      layout="fixed"
          width={100}
      height={25}
    />
            </>;

      case 'stackedwhite':
      return  
      <>
      <StaticImage
      src="./stacked/white.webp"
      alt="White Logor"
      placeholder="blurred"
      layout="fixed"
    width={25}
      height={100}
    />
    </>;
     case 'stackeddark':
      return  <>
      <StaticImage
      src="./stacked/black.webp"
      alt="BlackLogo"
      placeholder="blurred"
      layout="fixed"
    width={25}
      height={100}
    /></>;
    case 'symbol':
      return  <><StaticImage
      src="./symbol.svg"
      alt="Symbol"
      placeholder="blurred"
      layout="fixed"
      width={52}
      height={52}
    /></>;
    case 'abbreviation':
      return <> <StaticImage
      src="./abbreviation.webp"
      alt="Abbreviation"
      placeholder="blurred"
      layout="fixed"
    width={100}
      height={25}
    /></>;
    default:
     return <> <StaticImage
      src="./horizontal/white.webp"
      alt="Placeholder"
      placeholder="blurred"
      layout="fixed"
      width={100}
      height={25}
    /></>;
  }
  }
}


/**
 * Define component props
 */

   


LogoComponent.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.oneOf(['standard', 'darkversion', 'stackedwhite', 'stackeddark', 'symbol', 'abbreviation'].isRequired),

};
LogoComponent.defaultProps = {
  type: 'standard',
};
 

export default LogoComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not change component props directly

```
const {type} = this.props
this.props = {
  type: 'standard'
};
```

LogoComponent.defaultProps - will pass default props to component

Try to unpack values from props:

```
render() {
  const { type } = this.props;
  switch (type) {
    ...
```